# Unable to access a read-only Embedded Derby database from within EAR file deployed on JBoss server

Tags: embedded, jboss5.x, derby, ear

I am trying to access a read-only Embedded Derby database.  It is available as myDB.jar.  This jar has one folder of the Apache Derby database - myDB (log and seg0 folders and service.properties file).  This code works fine when I run from a file with a main method.  But, when I package it into EAR and deploy it on server it gives error.

This database is packaged with EAR file and deployed on JBoss 5.0.1 server.

The EAR has following contents:
•   myWebApp.war
•   myEjbs.jar
•   myDB.jar
•   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and META-INF/application.xml

Contents of MANIFEST.MF:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: myDB.jar

myDB.jar is not registered in application.xml

EJB-JAR i.e. myEjbs.jar has the following contents:
•   derby.properties
•   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and others such as persistence.xml, etc.  
Contents of MANIFEST.MF:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: myDB.jar
•   com.xxx.common.DbUtility.class that has the following code accessing the database:

```
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:jar:(myDB.jar)";
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
```

Connection con  = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+ dbName, user, password);

The output of this class is then used by the EJBs in com.xxx.ejbs package.

Following is the error I get:

INFO Loaded database driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

INFO SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(myDB.jar)myDB' with class loader BaseClassLoader@127627{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}, see the next exception for details.

INFO java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(myDB.jar)myDB' with class loader BaseClassLoader@127627{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}, see the next exception for details.

INFO at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  [STDOUT] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1)  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)

INFO  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)

INFO  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(myDB.jar)myDB' with class loader BaseClassLoader@127627{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}, see the next exception for details.

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)

INFO  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: 'myDB.jar (The system cannot find the file specified): java.io.FileNotFoundException'.

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.javaException(Unknown Source)

INFO  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: myDB.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.io.JarStorageFactory.doInit(Unknown Source)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.io.BaseStorageFactory.init(Unknown Source)

Thank you for your reply.  I have now tried the following:

(I)

```
String path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myDB.jar").getPath();
System.out.println("Path found = " + path);
private static String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:jar:" + "(" + path + ")";
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
```

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName, user, password);

It still gives the same error.  Following is the server log.

INFO  Path found = /C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/myDB.jar/

INFO  Loaded database driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

INFO  SQLException: Failed to start database 'jar:(/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/myDB.jar/)myDB' with class loader BaseClassLoader@e6c6d7{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}, see the next exception for details.

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Java exception: 'C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\deploy\Main.ear\ myDB.jar (The system cannot find the path specified): java.io.FileNotFoundException'.

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)

INFO  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\deploy\Main.ear\ myDB.jar (The system cannot find the path specified)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:114)

INFO  at java.util.zip.ZipFile.(ZipFile.java:131)

INFO  at org.apache.derby.impl.io.JarStorageFactory.doInit(Unknown Source)

Following is the output when classes are being loaded by JBoss initially:

BaseClassLoader@a75818{vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/} with policy VFSClassLoaderPolicy@88a588{name=vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/ domain=null roots=[MemoryContextHandler@19639558[path= context=vfsmemory://ak42v-bfhwq-ger46v84-1-ger477uj-20 real=vfsmemory://ak42v-bfhwq-ger46v84-1-ger477uj-20], DelegatingHandler@7111491[path=Main.ear context=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear], DelegatingHandler@1948811[path=Main.ear/myEJBs.jar context=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/myEJBs.jar], DelegatingHandler@4545587[path=Main.ear/ myDB.jar context=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/ real=file:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/Main.ear/ myDB.jar], com.xxx.common, com.xxx.ejb, myDB, myDB.seg0, META-INF, myDB.log, …

So it looks like the myDB.jar is in the classpath and the database folder myDB is also loaded.

(II)

Then I tried the following:

```
private static String dbURL_nfdc = "jdbc:derby:/";
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
```

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName, user, password);

I again get an error, but, now I do not get the FileNotFoundException:

INFO  java.sql.SQLException: Database '/myDB' not found.

INFO  Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database '/myDB' not found.

Looks like you have pointed me in the right direction, but, I am not able to find the reason for this error.

(III)

I also tried the following:

```
private static String dbURL_nfdc = "jdbc:derby:"; (No / )
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
```

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName, user, password);

But, get the same SQLException.

Is it possible that JBoss is treating myDB as a java package and not a simple file folder?

**The following worked:**

```
private static String dbURL_nfdc = "jdbc:derby:classpath:/";
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";
```

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName, user, password);

Thank you so much for leading me in the right direction. Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since your database jar is inside your same EJB ear package, I think it is supposed to be "in the classpath", so you should try following the "in the classpath" section of the docs at http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/devguide/cdevdvlp24155.html#cdevdvlp24155.

That is, I don't think you want to use the "jar" sub-protocol.

Alternatively, if you are going to use the "jar" sub-protocol, then I think that the part inside the parentheses should be the full filesystem path of your ejb ear file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am not sure if I am able to add my whole comment here, but, I have edited my question to include what I tried based on your answer.  Appreciate if you could please review it there.  Thanks again.

Comment: <p>
The following worked:
</p><p>
<font size=2><pre>
private static String dbURL_nfdc = "jdbc:derby:classpath:/";
private static String dbName = "myDB";
private static String user = "";
private static String password = "";

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL+dbName, user, password);
</pre></font>
<p>
Thank you so much for leading me in the right direction. Appreciate your help!!!
</p>